# Get month name in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to get somehow **name of given month** (by its number) in Symfony's controller. And in **current locale**.

Form's date widget translates month to current locale automatically. I would like do the same but in my controller.

I know how get [country](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/country.html#choices) translated but didn't found the same funtionality for month.

Thanks

---

**Solution** doesn't rely on Symfony components (except locale):

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $this->request->getLocale());
    $month = strftime("%B", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthId, 1, 2000));
```

Comment: Not sure, but have a look to http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html

Comment: strftime has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look at official [ICU docs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) for date formatting. ICU is underlying component for `Intl` (mentioned by Yann in comments above).

So, given that variable `$monthId` contains the number of month, you could do:

```
$monthId = ....
$date = new \DateTime();

# Overwrite the date with first day in the month
$y = (int)$date->format('Y');
$date->setDate($y, $monthId, 1); 

# Create a formatter
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US', // Your locale?
    "LLLL", // <--- This is the LONG MONTH format
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Los_Angeles', // Time zone, not important in this case
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
);

# Format the month
$monthName = $fmt->format($date);
```

Hope this helps...

---

Comment: It should work but I got this error: `The Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter::__construct() method's argument $locale value 'fr' behavior is not implemented. Only the locale "en" is supported. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.`.

Comment: And the solution is sooo simple: `setlocale(LC_ALL, $this->request->getLocale()); return strftime("%B", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthId, 1, 2000));`

Comment: Oh, very simple indeed. Please include it as your own answer :) It certainly is much prettier than mine and should be upvoted :)

Comment: If y change the constructor call as following, it will work:
        $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
            'en_US',
            IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
            IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
            $dateTime->getTimezone(),
            IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
            'LLLL'
        );